Can BitBucket be accessed by OIDC?
I’m trying to deploy an automated process (like renovatebot running in Kubernetes) that needs to push commits to a private BitBucket repo.
Is it possible to use OIDC for authorising access to the repo? Does it require a third-party BitBucket App or plug-in? Do I need to package my code as an Atlassian Connect app?
